# Package Loading Problems

Tags: r, package

I have problems of loading this package called **equatiomatic**

I have successfully installed, but when I library it using `library(equatiomatic)`，the following error message appears.

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘equatiomatic’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace ‘htmltools’ 0.5.1.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.2 is required`

Can any one tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to update htmltools then load equatiomatic, e.g.

```
# restart or start a new session to 'unload' all libraries

# install htmltools
install.packages("htmltools")

# load equatiomatic
library(equatiomatic)
```